# is there a reference for making login access using face recognition with openface, desktop-based python

Tags: python, face-recognition

I want to build a desktop program whose logins use face identifiers using the openface method, but when I research on the internet it is mostly used in real time videos and there is no example for login access is there a reference for me to start this project, I built it using python

Comment: Are you trying to make an authentication provider for an operating system or just for your application?

Comment: only for my application, sir